failed to load resource err_connection_closed
We have a web application that is hosted in IIS. When one of our clients tries to access a process of our application they are getting "Failed to load resource err_connection_closed" error message in their console and the page is stuck (Processing modal pop up doesn't go away).
We checked our database while they were running the process and database part is completed in 12 minutes (It is a lengthy process) but they are not getting the result.
This happens only when client access our software from their office. We logged in to their live website from our location and we can complete the process successfully.
They are using Chrome and yes, we checked their pop-up block and made them to try in incognito mode to disable extensions. Nothing worked.

If a single HTTP request is expected to take 12 minutes then I wouldn't be at all surprised if the browser or any point between the browser and the server would consider that a timeout.  A process which takes that long should be offloaded from the HTTP request itself and handled externally from processing that request.  For example, the web application could place a message on a queue or even just a record in a database and then immediately return to the user.  Then a background task of some sort can respond to that message and perform the long-running task.

As David says, an HTTP connection can get terminated for all sorts of reasons, so you should never be relying on it to stay open for so long. There are possibly various things in between your clients office and your webserver that have limits on durations, firewalls, proxies etc. often have this kind of thing built in.

The issue you describe may be related to some limitations or configurations in the customer's office network environment. Firewalls or proxy servers at the customer's office may interrupt long-running HTTP requests.

You can make it asynchronous and set up a WebSocket connection in this case
